# Why does this sed regex substitution not work?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file with id's for which I want to create db INSERT's.
The SQL I want to use: `INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'id_from_file', now(), 'HERC-742');`

I'm using `sed` with regex but the substitution seems to mess up the result.

File with id's:

```
$ cat object_ids_01.sql 
09ab41308002760e                                                
09ab41308002760f                                                
09ab413080027610                                                
09ab413080027611                                                
...
```

When I run this command:
`$ sed -E "s/(.*)/INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms \(id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker\) VALUES \(uuid_generate_v4\(\), \'\1\', now\(\), \'HERC-742\'\);/" object_ids_01.sql > output.sql`

I get these results:

```
$ cat output.sql 
', now(), 'HERC-742');igratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), '09ab41308002760e                                                
', now(), 'HERC-742');igratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), '09ab41308002760f                                                
', now(), 'HERC-742');igratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), '09ab413080027610                                                
', now(), 'HERC-742');igratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), '09ab413080027611
...
```

It seems the `\1` is at fault because when I replace it with a constant string I get decent INSERT's:

```
$ sed -E "s/(.*)/INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms \(id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker\) VALUES \(uuid_generate_v4\(\), \'xxxxxx\', now\(\), \'HERC-742\'\);/" object_ids_01.sql > output.sql
$ cat output.sql 
INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'xxxxxx', now(), 'HERC-742');
INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'xxxxxx', now(), 'HERC-742');
INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'xxxxxx', now(), 'HERC-742');
INSERT INTO docstore.migratie_dms (id, document_id, creatiedatum, gebruiker) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), 'xxxxxx', now(), 'HERC-742');
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(.*)` might be picking up more than you think. Seeing that these appear to be alphanumeric in nature, what if you replace with `(\w+)`?

Comment: Your input probably has trailing white space which `(.*)` is picking. `([^[:space:]]*)` seems to work.

Comment: @automaton: yes, that does the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @npinti: you were on the right track but your solution didn't do it as I have some UUID's in the file that have dashes.

Comment: @Koohoolinn: In that case `[A-Za-z0-9_-]` would also do the trick instead of `\w`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input probably has trailing white space which `(.*)` is picking. `([^[:space:]]*)` seems to work.